# Scrape a table from multiple pages and store in a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

**Problem**: a website has c.80 pages, each of which contains a single table that is identically structured. I need to scrape each table and store the results in a single pandas dataframe. The table content is regularly updated, and therefore the exercise will need to be frequently repeated.

I can scrape the table from a single page but am struggling to do it for multiple pages. All of the examples I have found are for URLs that change iteratively, e.g. (www.example.com/page1, /page2 etc), rather than for a specified list of URLs.

I have tried the following for a subset of the URLs (ideally, I would like to read in the URLs from a csv list), but it only seems to scrape the final table into the dataframe (i.e. ZZ).

Apologies if this seems dim, I’m fairly new to `Python` and have mainly been using `pandas` for data analysis, reading in directly from `csv`. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

How can I read the URLs from a csv list ? my current solution does not scrape the whole table as I expect.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

COLUMNS = ['ID', 'Serial', 'Aircraft', 'Notes']

urls = ['http://www.ukserials.com/results.php?serial=ZR',
'http://www.ukserials.com/results.php?serial=ZT',
'http://www.ukserials.com/results.php?serial=ZZ']
#scrape elements
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    table = soup.find("table") # Find the "table" tag in the page
    rows = table.find_all("tr") # Find all the "tr" tags in the table
    cy_data = [] 
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.find_all("td") #  Find all the "td" tags in each row 
        cells = cells[0:4] # Select the correct columns
        cy_data.append([cell.text for cell in cells]) # For each "td" tag, get the text inside it

data = pd.DataFrame(cy_data, columns=COLUMNS).drop(0, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not add each dataframe into a list, and then merge the elements of that list right at the end?

```
...
dataframes = []
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    table = soup.find("table") # Find the "table" tag in the page
    rows = table.find_all("tr") # Find all the "tr" tags in the table
    cy_data = []
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.find_all("td") #  Find all the "td" tags in each row
        cells = cells[0:4] # Select the correct columns
        cy_data.append([cell.text for cell in cells]) # For each "td" tag, get the text inside it

    dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame(cy_data, columns=COLUMNS).drop(0, axis=0))

data = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

Note: You might need to specify index offsets for each dataframe (before merging), as seen here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: Thanks for the very quick help on this - your solution works perfectly.